# If two cosets are equal how can we conclude this

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $aH=bH$ where $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$

Then $$a=bh\quad \text{for}\quad h \in H.$$

I couldn't understand why. $a$ and $b$ are any numbers from the group $G$. How come some number I chose from $G$ satisfies the condition above. Is there any proof behind this, since I couldn't manage to find one. Thanks

Comment: Hint: write down what $aH=bH$ means in terms of the elements

Comment: Elements of a group need not be numbers by the way.

Comment: $a\in aH$ and $aH=bH$ implies $a\in bH$ which means $a=bh$ for some $h\in H$.